# Menu in C++ using pointers and functions

Tags: c++, pointers

My objective to display a menu in which user chooses between 5 functions (1-5). After function runs and outputs its data. At the end the user chooses between functions (1-5) again.

My (incorrect) semi-code:

```
int main(){


int option;
int *pOption = &option;

bool choice = true;

cout << "Main menu: 

cout << "To use function 1 enter 1. \n";
cout << "To use function 2 enter 2. \n";
cout << "To use function 3 enter 3. \n";
cout << "To exit please enter 0. \n";
cin >> option;

while (choice == true) {

    if (option == 1) {
        cout << "You picked Function one: ";
        functionOne(Variable);
    }
    if (option == 2) {
        cout << "You picked Function 2: ";
        functionOne(Variable);
    }
    if (option == 3) {
        cout << "You picked Function 3: ";
        functionOne(Variable);
    }
}//end of while loop
return 0;

 }
```

For example lets say the user hits option 1 and goes to this function below. After we do our output how can I utilize the pointer 'pOption' I created to select a new function to use? Or am I completely missing the ball?

```
  void functionOne(Variable){

 cout<< "This is function 1";

 cin >>pOption;

 return;
 }
```

Comment: Why not give a try on your own using it and update the question with outcome.

Comment: Sorry, my english is not too good. I did try it, and it doesn't compile because of `code: cin>>pOption;` I will edit my post and ask my question better thanks!

Comment: I don't knoe, what you are trying to use pOption for, but the answer is most likely to go through a c++ tutorial and/or read a book.

Comment: @MikeMB Thanks, appreciate the advice. I was trying to change the value of Option in my main function by using the pointer pOption. Will do more research on the web and let you know what I find. :)

Comment: Aside from the fact that this would be rather bad design, in this case you would have to pass that pointer to the function and dereference it there in order to be used with `cin >>`. The reason I'm suggesting a C++ book is tthatthis will teach you the basics of c++ in a much more structured manner than searching the solution for each problem in the web individually.Especially, if you don't know thr language fundamentals yet

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to stick with what seems to be the main question and get to the other bits of if I have time before the battery runs out.

Rather than ask for the next option insidea called function, do it in the main function like this:

```
cin >> option;

while (0 != option) <-exit loop if option is zero
{
    if (option == 1) {
        cout << "You picked Function one: ";
        functionOne(Variable);
    }
    if (option == 2) {
        cout << "You picked Function 2: ";
        functionOne(Variable);
    }
    if (option == 3) {
        cout << "You picked Function 3: ";
        functionOne(Variable);
    }
    cin >> option; <- ask for next option here
}//end of while loop
```

Next, you can save a bit of hassle by reading up on `else if` and `switch`

```
cin >> option;

while (0 != option) 
{
    switch (option) {
        case 1:
            cout << "You picked Function one: ";
            functionOne(Variable);
            break;
        case 2:
            cout << "You picked Function 2: ";
            functionOne(Variable);
            break;
        case 3:
            cout << "You picked Function 3: ";
            functionOne(Variable);
            break;
        default:
            cout << "You picked an unsupported option: " << option;

    }
    cin >> option; 
}//end of while loop
```

Next, what if some fool types in "I'm not a number, sucker" for option? Read up on input validation. Google's your friend here, not me anymore. MY battery's at 3% and I'm shutting down. Bye.

Comment: @user4581303 Your answer is highly appreciated! However although your method is correct. I wanted to see if there was a way I could point to the 'option' variable from my function to change it there. Thanks Again though! Hopefully I didn't waste too much of your battery.

Comment: Not recommended, but all you need to do is pass the pointer into the function as a call parameter. Prototype: `void functionOne(int * pOption)`. Call: `functionOne(&option);`. Still not recommended, but almost infinitely better is to use a reference in place of the pointer. Prototype: `void functionOne(int & option)`. Call: `functionOne(option);`. [Read up on pointers and references.](https://isocpp.org/images/uploads/2-Tour-Basics.pdf)

Comment: And no worries. I'd been using the tablet all night and it was just out of juice.